# Does a mutex still need to be released if it times-out?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, synchronization

Using the [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Function.

If the function is called and times out, does it still need to release the mutex?

i.e. should ReleaseMutex be in position `1.` or `2.` if the five seconds elapse?

```
WaitForSingleObject(5 second time out)
{
  //access shared resource

  //1. - ReleaseMutex() here?
}
  //2. - ReleaseMutex() here?
```

Comment: If you never acquire it why would you need to release it?

Comment: I don't know how it works, that is why I am asking ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. If the call to `WaitForSingleObject` times out then you have not acquired the mutex, so should not release it.

i.e. you only need `ReleaseMutex` at position 1.

Answer (score 2):

Your case #1 is correct.  If you time out on that call, it means the resource was not acquired and you should not attempt to release it.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to release the mutex if you got ownership.  Note that there are 4 possible return values, in 2 cases you get ownership, and in 2 you do not.

WAIT_ABANDONED - you got ownership and need to release the mutex, but the previous owner terminated without explicitly releasing the mutext so shared state may be inconsistent.

WAIT_OBJECT_0 - you got the ownership.  You need to release the mutext.

WAIT_TIMEOUT - the mutext was not released for the duration of timeout

WAIT_FAILED - usually due to a bug in your code (i.e. invalid handle).